# How do I extend an ES6 class with ES5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

The reasons for doing this are complicated, but it boils down to flow not understanding mixins or any other way of modifying an ES6 class's prototype.  So I'm falling back to ES5, but I can't figure out how to call the constructor of an ES6 class without `new`:

```
class A {
  constructor() {}
}

function B() {
  // what do I put here?  I would do something like
  // A.prototype.constructor.call(this) but that throws an error saying the
  // constructor can only be called with `new`
}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to avoid using `new`? I think calling `new` is the only (and is the *correct*) way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this myself:

```
class A {
  constructor() {}
}

function B() {
  Object.assign(this, new A());
}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
```

Not sure if there are any side-effects here or not

Comment: I thought you want to call the constructor without `new` ?

Comment: Anyway, most probably in no way we can skip the keyword `new` based on my understanding from this spec http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget

Comment: I just want B to extend A, the ES5 way of doing that is to do `A.call(this)` from within B, sorry if the phrasing in my question implied a different intent